# SQL Sum double counting

Tags: sql

My SQL is double counting 'Fund1Amount' and 'Fund2Amount' and 'TotalAllDonations' I have a record where the values of the FundAmount1 should = 10 and FundAmount2 should = 20 but they equal 20 & 40 and the total is double. I am using INNER JOINs twice on the same table abc_donationdetail which i am not sure if this is the problem.

```
SELECT
    C.FirstName, C.LastName, 
    SUM(D.abc_totalamount) AS TotalAllDonations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DBU.abc_fundidname = 'Fund1' THEN DBU.abc_amount END) AS Fund1Amount, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DBE.abc_fundidname = 'Fund2' THEN DBE.abc_amount END) AS Fund2Amount
FROM
    Contact C 
INNER JOIN
    Account A ON C.parentcustomerid = A.accountid 
INNER JOIN
    Account PA ON A.parentaccountid = PA.accountid 
INNER JOIN
    abc_donation D ON D.abc_person = C.contactid 
LEFT JOIN
    abc_donationdetail DBU ON DBU.abc_donationid = D.abc_donationid 
                           AND DBU.abc_fundidname= 'Fund1' 
LEFT JOIN
    abc_donationdetail DBE ON DBE.abc_donationid = D.abc_donationid 
                           AND DBE.abc_fundidname = 'Fund2' 
LEFT JOIN
    abc_mmcs GD ON GD.abc_donor = C.contactid 
LEFT JOIN 
    sab_item LIBU ON LIBU.sab_itemid = GD.abc_companyid 
                  AND LIBU.sab_name = 'Fund1' 
LEFT JOIN
    sab_item LIBE ON LIBE.sab_itemid = GD.abc_companyid 
                  AND LIBE.sab_name = 'Fund2'
```

where C.StateCode = 0 AND (GD.abc_enddate > GETDATE() or GD.abc_enddate IS NULL)

group by C.abc_memberid, C.FirstName, C.LastName , C.StateCode, A.name, A.parentaccountidname, A.dd_number, PA.dd_number, C.parentcustomeridname
order by C.lastname

**Current**

```
FN       LN   Total    Fund1    Fund2
James   Brown   70      40       30
Phillip Smith   160     60       100
Peter   Jones   80      40       40
Vincent Limp    48      48       NULL
Michael Collins 60      60       NULL
```

**Desired**

```
FN       LN    Total    Fund1   Fund2
James   Brown   35       20      15
Phillip Smith   80       30      50
Peter   Jones   40       20      20
Vincent Limp    24       24     NULL
Michael Collins 30       30     NULL
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing your data. It sounds like you have a case where there are two abc_donationdetail records from Fund1, and two abc_donationdetail records from Fund1 for the same abc_donationid. In that case your joins are the issue.
If you show the unexpected result and the data behind that result, then it's possible to provide a better answer.

Comment: Double counting occurs when I have record that has a person that has a donation for fund1 and fund2. Each donation has its own I’d and can either be for fund1 or fund2 not both. I want to sum the totals for each in one row on a report .

Comment: add sample data and current and desired result.

Comment: added current and desired result above but for some reason its unformatted the table

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only in duplicates, than simply make a subquery:

```
Select fld, sum(value)
from (select distinct fld, value from tbl) as a
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say much here as there are lots of tables joined here and I don't know their schema. At most, I can suggest you to add group by with person's id and fund id as it'll remove the duplicates.

```
    SELECT
    C.FirstName, C.LastName, 
    SUM(D.abc_totalamount) AS TotalAllDonations,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DBU.abc_fundidname = 'Fund1' THEN DBU.abc_amount END) AS Fund1Amount, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN DBU.abc_fundidname = 'Fund2' THEN DBU.abc_amount END) AS Fund2Amount
FROM
    Contact C 
INNER JOIN
    Account A ON C.parentcustomerid = A.accountid 
INNER JOIN
    Account PA ON A.parentaccountid = PA.accountid 
INNER JOIN
    abc_donation D ON D.abc_person = C.contactid 
LEFT JOIN
    abc_donationdetail DBU ON DBU.abc_donationid = D.abc_donationid 
                           AND (DBU.abc_fundidname= 'Fund1' 
                           OR   DBU.abc_fundidname = 'Fund2')    //MERGED 2 JOINS
LEFT JOIN
    abc_mmcs GD ON GD.abc_donor = C.contactid 
LEFT JOIN 
    sab_item LIBU ON LIBU.sab_itemid = GD.abc_companyid 
                  AND LIBU.sab_name = 'Fund1' 
LEFT JOIN
    sab_item LIBE ON LIBE.sab_itemid = GD.abc_companyid 
                  AND LIBE.sab_name = 'Fund2'
where C.StateCode = 0 AND (GD.abc_enddate > GETDATE() or GD.abc_enddate IS NULL)

group by C.abc_memberid, C.FirstName, C.LastName , C.StateCode, A.name, A.parentaccountidname, A.dd_number, PA.dd_number, C.parentcustomeridname order by C.lastname
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Hi Harshill no it is not. Adding the grouping you mentioned makes it adds a duplicate lines. I have added my full query above, which has grouping and order by.

Comment: The reason of duplication is that you are  joining abc_donationdetail using name field. Just join with the use of Id and add conditions related to name in where clause. A small and simple example is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39e4e5/7/1

Comment: Hi Harshill I am joining abc_donationdetail on id not name “abc_donationdetail DBU ON DBU.abc_donationid = D.abc_donationid 
                           AND DBU.abc_fundidname= 'Fund1' ”

Comment: Yeah...that should not be a problem.

Comment: Can you create test database on sqlfiddle or rextester? And please tell which database you are using.

Comment: Turns out the problem exist because you have 2 left joins with same table abc.donationdetail . I merged both join in one using OR condition and also modified the alias in case statement. This should work properly now. Please try the edited query.

Comment: Sorry just tried that and still doubling the amounts on the sum. Any more ideas?

Comment: Can you create test database on sqlfiddle or rextester? And please tell which database you are using.

Comment: Also please tell how do you store values in abc_donation.abc_totalAmount?

Comment: I am very new to sql and not sure how to use sqlfiddle and Rextester. What do you mean how do I store the total amount ?

Comment: go to rextester.com. Select your database(mysql , oracle etc) Add all your create, insert and select queries. save it. It will generate a URL. share the url here in comment. OR you can add your create and insert queries in your question itself.

Comment: not sure if this helps http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc494/2/0 as i say I am new to this.

Comment: Can you tell me what values does D.abc_totalamount field contains?

Comment: The abc.totalamount field contains the values I put on  Sqlfiddle . I have commented out some lines and found out the duplication disappears when I comment out LEFT JOIN
    abc_mmcs GD ON GD.abc_donor = C.contactid .

Comment: That's what I was trying to tell you. I told you to create sqlfiddle with all the tables you joined in your query. Then only I could find why duplication is happening. Anyways, glad you find out the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Also a suggestion: you already have c.statecode = 0 inside where. So you don't need to add that in group by.

Comment: Don't you need the conditions in where clause with abc_enddate? I mean if those condition are required, then you can't just comment out the join condition.

Comment: If the above answer solved/helped you to solve the problem  than kindly accept the answer and/or upvote the answer. Thank  you.